# Problem studying stationary points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I have this function:$$f(x,y)=\frac{10+x^2y^2}{e^{x^2+y^2} }$$
I have found that the only stationary point is $(0,0)$ but I don't know ho to classify it as a max, min or saddle point. Can someone help me?
(I could study it using the determinant of the Hessian but I'm looking for another solution)

[image: The Hessian matrix]

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Aside; you could reduce the calculation by using the trick $$ \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial u} g(u,v)\right)_{(u,v)=0} = \left( \frac{d}{du} g(u,0)\right)_{u=0} $$

Comment: You can tell it's not a saddle point because the two variables are symmetric (ie if you swapped $x$ with $y$ in the function definition it would still be the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing in polar form with the substitutions

$$\begin{aligned} x &= r \cos \theta & y &= r \sin \theta \end{aligned}$$

gives

$$ f = \frac{10 + r^4 (\cos \theta \sin \theta)^2}{e^{r^2}} $$

Defining $t =  (\cos \theta \sin \theta)^2$ and expanding

$$ e^{-r^2} = 1 - r^2 + \frac{1}{2}r^4 - o(r^6) $$

before multiplying gives

$$\begin{aligned}
f &= 10 - 10 r^2 + (5 + t) r^4 - o(r^6) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} f &= -20 r + 4(5+t) r^3 - o(r^5) \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} f &= -20 + 12(5 + t)r^2 - o(r^4) \\
&< 0 &r=0, \forall \theta
\end{aligned}$$

That is, $f_\theta(r)$ has a maximum at $r = 0$ for all $\theta$.  Therefore $f(x, y)$ must have a maximum at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Very good solution. Is it possible to determinate saddle points with this method?

Answer (score 3):

You could taylor expand to second order $$ f(x,y) = 10e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1+x^2y^2)\approx 10(1-(x^2+y^2))(1) =  10-10(x^2+y^2)$$

and infer that it's a local maximum (since it's an upside down paraboloid).

Answer (score 2):

> *Method 1*. One may observe that, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> 10-f(x,y)&=10-10e^{-(x^2+y^2)}-x^2y^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}
> \\\\&=10-10e^{-(x^2+y^2)}-o(x^2+y^2)
> \\\\&=10-10[1-(x^2+y^2)+o(x^2+y^2)]-o(x^2+y^2)
> \\\\&=10(x^2+y^2)+o(x^2+y^2)
> \end{align}
> $$ which is *non-negative* as as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

*Method 2*. One may use the [second derivative test for functions of two variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#The_test), that is evaluating
$$
D(x,y)= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) - \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial xy}(x,y) \right)^2
$$ at $(0,0)$  checking if $D(0,0)>0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(0,0)<0$ to know if it is a local maximum.

Comment: I know. But the I'm trying to avoid to calculate the second derivative. The amount of calculus is huge

Comment: @FedericoZucchi Ok, you can use the fact that $e^{-t}=1-t+t^2/2+o(t^2)$ as $t \to 0$. Here $t=x^2+y^2$ giving an expansion for $\frac{1}{e^{x^2+y^2} }=e^{-(x^2+y^2)} $.

Comment: And what about considering that the function is always positive? Is it important?

Comment: It won't be sufficient.

Comment: Ok. Your method is valid but how am I supposed to manage the $x^2y^2$ with your substition?

Comment: With the expansion I've given in my comment above, one sees that, near $(0,0)$, one has$10-f(x,y)=10(x^2+y^2)+o(x^2+y^2)\ge0$. In fact $x^2y^2$ is much smaller compared to $x^2+y^2$ so it goes into $o(x^2+y^2)$. Do you see that?

Comment: Now I see that. Thanks

Comment: @FedericoZucchi You are welcome.

Comment: I see, and what if the point was a saddle?  How can I figure out with your method?

Comment: Here the sign is *constant* near $(0,0)$, if the sign were *non constant* there would be a saddle point...